# Why does wrapping host code in __CUDA_ARCH__ cause an invalid device functor error?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Take the following code for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct print_func {
    __device__ __host__ void operator()(int i) {
        printf("%d, ", i);
    }
};

struct functor {
    __device__ __host__ bool operator()(int i) {
        return i % 2 == 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    thrust::device_vector<int> vec(10);
    thrust::sequence(vec.begin(), vec.end());

//#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    auto newLast = thrust::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), functor());
    vec.resize(thrust::distance(vec.begin(), newLast));
    thrust::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), print_func());
//#endif
}
```

In it, if you uncomment the preprocessor condition (which should theoretically have no impact, as `__CUDA_ARCH__` is not defined on host side), suddenly a `CUDA error 98: invalid device function` runtime error is thrown.

**Why is this, and how would I go about properly resolving this?**

For some additional context, I ran into this problem while trying to implement separate host and device code from a single `__host__ __device__` function.

Comment: [Can't reproduce this on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jne5xP6v7). Perhaps the issue is with your individual system?

Comment: @einpoklum: How would Godbolt generate a **runtime** error?

Comment: "For some additional context, I ran into this problem while trying to implement separate host and device code from a single `__host__ __device__` function" -- you can't do that. The language doesn't allow it

Comment: And your preprocessor definition is breaking the compilation trajectory. Despite what you think happens, that thrust code emits both host and device code, both of which must be compiled. Your preprocessor stanza is preventing some necessary runtime boilerplate from being emitted and breaking everything

Comment: @talonmies It is absolutely possible to have a `__host__ __device__` function in cuda, and as of version 3.0 I believe you can use `__CUDA_ARCH__` to split device and host code apart in said function. [This is the earliest example of this I can find.](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/13433/3)

Comment: Thrust is a templated library.  That thing that you claim is host code is actually a mixture of host and device code.  Wrapping that in the `#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__` will cause the compilation process to break.  During the device code compilation phase, `__CUDA_ARCH__` is defined, so you are preventing the inclusion/compilation of the device code associated e.g. with the `thrust::remove_if` call. You would properly resolve it by not doing that.  If you have some other context that you think such a thing is needed, then you would need to provide a better description of that.

Comment: I think if you want to put this sort of code in the host path of a `__host__ __device__` function, what I would do is wrap that path normally, and then place a function call in that path to another function, defined elsewhere, without the macro wrap, that calls whatever you want to call from thrust.

Comment: @Thane: I think you need to read all the words I wrote again. I didn't say you can't have `__host__ __device__` functions. I said you can't (or shouldn't) have different implementations of the same `__host__ __device__` function on the host and the device. The entire point of that declaration is "here is some code which I want the compiler to compile on both the host and device". You can see in your example how you will break stuff if you do

Comment: @RobertCrovella oh, I understand now! Now that you've said that, the problem seems so obvious I'm embarrassed I didn't catch it myself. Thank you so much for the explanation. I'll post a self-answer just in case someone finds this googling, but if you'd like to iterate further on it, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the very enlightening comment by Robert Crovella, the issue is because thrust will not get a chance to include its device-side code during that compilation step. A rudimentary fix would be something like the following:

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct print_func {
    __device__ __host__ void operator()(int i) {
        printf("%d, ", i);
    }
};

struct functor {
    __device__ __host__ bool operator()(int i) {
        return i % 2 == 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    thrust::device_vector<int> vec(10);
    thrust::sequence(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    if (THRUST_IS_HOST_CODE) {
        auto newLast = thrust::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), functor());
        vec.resize(thrust::distance(vec.begin(), newLast));
        thrust::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), print_func());
    }
}
```

But, there are still limitations to this strategy. For instance, this will not compile if you call any device-only functions. Because of this, this kind of implementation should be avoided.